# utilizing C# microsoft assemblies that are not in the GAC

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, .net-assembly, gac

My computer only has VS2019 installed with .net versions up to 4.8. I'm attempting to use the Microsoft.Build.Construction assemblies in a program i'm working on. When i go to add the reference->Assemblies, the only versions i have are 4.0.0.0. Based on my research, VS stopped adding assemblies to the GAC, so i'm forced to manually add the DLL from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin in order to utilize the Version 15.1.0.0 that at least supports the SolutionFile calls.

So my question is this: should i push those versions to the GAC in order to be able to use them, or is there a better way to access non-GAC assemblies than how i did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For MSBuild assemblies, you must follow the guidance of Microsoft strictly to avoid all side efforts. In general, the NuGet packages are recommended.

> ## Change MSBuild references
>
> To make sure that MSBuild loads from a central location, you must not distribute its assemblies with your application.
>
> The mechanism for changing your project to avoid loading MSBuild from a central location depends on how you reference MSBuild.
>
> ### Use NuGet packages (preferred)

For detailed information, please check out the long [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/updating-an-existing-application?view=vs-2019)

Answer (score 1):

Forget the GAC, just take the DLL in the Bin folder, copy it to your project folder in /References, and reference it from there. This way if you use version control, the specific version of the DLL follows the source code.

EDIT: As mentioned by Lex below, this is not a suitable solution for MSBuild assemblies, you should use the Nuget package instead.

Comment: I didn't even consider that!

Comment: Note that you may also be able to reference the assembly via a .NET Standard Nuget package, but that is useful when you want to keep the DLL updated, and in my own experience it can cause more issues than necessary...

Comment: This might sound right for general assemblies, but unfortunately not for MSBuild assemblies.

Comment: Ah! See, learn something new every day... Go with the Nuget package then!